# Why won't my promise.all return data even though it works

Tags: promise, stripe-payments

I am running the following code:

```
    let Payment =   relevantWaitList.map(e => {


        stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: Math.round(e.totalCharge * 100),
            currency: currency,
            description: `Resale of ${eventData.title} refunded ticket`,
            // customer: customerStripeID,
            payment_method: e.paymentMethod,
            off_session: true,
            confirm: true,
            application_fee_amount: Math.round(e.applicationFee*100)
        }
        ,{
        stripe_account: organiserStripeAccountID,
        }
    )
})


    Promise.all(Payment)
    .then(data => {
        console.log('promiseall payment res', data)
         }).catch(err => {
           console.log('promise all payment fail', err)}
```

Which is returning the following:

```
promiseall payment res undefined
```

Despite it returning undefined, the promise.all is working - the stripe payments intents are created.

When I change to promise to include the .then within the map (using the code below), it console logs fine but I would prefer to play with the data after all promises have been completed.

What am I missing?

```
    let Payment =   relevantWaitList.map(e => {


        stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: Math.round(e.totalCharge * 100),
            currency: currency,
            description: `Resale of ${eventData.title} refunded ticket`,
            // customer: customerStripeID,
            payment_method: e.paymentMethod,
            off_session: true,
            confirm: true,
            application_fee_amount: Math.round(e.applicationFee*100)
        }
        ,{
        stripe_account: organiserStripeAccountID,
        }
    )
     .then(data => console.log('data within map', data))
     .catch(err => console.log('err within map', err))
})
```

Comment: Your `.map()` callback does not return anything which means it will just return an array of `undefined`, giving `Promise.all()` no promises and no data to use.  What you need to be passing `Promise.all()` is an array of promises that each resolve to a value, then `Promise.all()` will return a promise that will resolve to an array of those values.  In this case, you have garbage into `Promise.all()` and therefore garbage out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.map()` callback does not return anything which means that `.map()` will just return an array of `undefined`, giving `Promise.all()` no promises and no data to use.

What you need to be passing `Promise.all()` is an array of promises that each resolve to a value, then `Promise.all()` will return a promise that will resolve to an array of those values. In this case, you have garbage into `Promise.all()` and therefore garbage out.

So, your `.map()` callback should be returning a promise that resolves to the value you eventually want.

Assuming `stripe.paymentIntents.create()` returns a promise that resolves to a value you want, you just need to add a return statement:

```
    let Payment = relevantWaitList.map(e => {

        // ******* Add return on next line *********
        return stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: Math.round(e.totalCharge * 100),
            currency: currency,
            description: `Resale of ${eventData.title} refunded ticket`,
            // customer: customerStripeID,
            payment_method: e.paymentMethod,
            off_session: true,
            confirm: true,
            application_fee_amount: Math.round(e.applicationFee*100)
        } , {stripe_account: organiserStripeAccountID,
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer from @jfriend00, your map callback does not return anything.

You need to return the Promise object for each iteration

```
const payments = relevantWaitList.map(e => {
  return stripe.paymentIntents.create({ 
    // your props
  });
});
```

The `payments` variable now contains an array of promises. You can use `Promise.all()` now

```
Promise.all(payments).then(data =>{
  // play with data here :)
});
```